# Is There a Way of Switching Tabs in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First of all I want to give you the link before I forget.

http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1

Towards the bottom of the page there are multiple tabs.  (Gear, Hats, Faces, Packages, etc.)

```
function checkForHat() {
    $.get (
        'http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1',

        function parse(data) {
            var hatid1 = $(data).find('#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserAssetsPane_UserAssetsDataList_ctl00_AssetThumbnailHyperLink');
            var hatidtitle1 = hatid1.attr('title');
            var hatidhref1 = "http://www.roblox.com" + hatid1.attr('href');
            var hatidpi1 = $(hatid1).find('img')
            var hatidpic1 = hatidpi1.attr('src')
            hatLink1 = hatidhref1;
            hatTitle1 = hatidtitle1;
            hatPic1 = hatidpic1;
            var hatid2 = $(data).find('#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserAssetsPane_UserAssetsDataList_ctl01_AssetThumbnailHyperLink');
            var hatidtitle2 = hatid2.attr('title');
            var hatidhref2 = "http://www.roblox.com" + hatid2.attr('href');
            var hatidpi2 = $(hatid2).find('img')
            var hatidpic2 = hatidpi2.attr('src')
            hatLink2 = hatidhref2;
            hatTitle2 = hatidtitle2;
            hatPic2 = hatidpic2;
            var hatid3 = $(data).find('#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserAssetsPane_UserAssetsDataList_ctl02_AssetThumbnailHyperLink');
            var hatidtitle3 = hatid3.attr('title');
            var hatidhref3 = "http://www.roblox.com" + hatid3.attr('href');
            var hatidpi3 = $(hatid3).find('img')
            var hatidpic3 = hatidpi3.attr('src')
            hatLink3 = hatidhref3;
            hatTitle3 = hatidtitle3;
            hatPic3 = hatidpic3;
            if (hatLink3 != null && hatTitle3 != null && hatPic3 != null) {
                checkIfNew3();
            }
            if (hatLink2 != null && hatTitle2 != null && hatPic2 != null) {
                checkIfNew2();
            }
            if (hatLink1 != null && hatTitle1 != null && hatPic1 != null) {
                checkIfNew1();
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Of course some of the variables are already called earlier in the code.

Now my question is how to change tabs with JQuery.  Like I said the tabs are towards the bottom.

This answer is starting to become vital because I have alot of requests for an upgrade on the chrome extension that this is in.

Thanks.

Comment: What tabs are you talking about? How does the code in the question pertain to "switching tabs with jQuery?"

Comment: Looks like the perfect job for AJAX/json

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the javascript used to execute tab switching is held in the href attribute. You can execute eval on that method.

```
//this will click the shirts tab     
eval($('#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserAssetsPane_AssetCategoryRepeater_ctl05_AssetCategorySelector').attr('href'))
```

If you want something a little more robust then:

```
$shirtElem = $('#assetsMenu a').filter( function() {
     if ($(this).html() == 'Shirts') return true;
});
eval($shirtElem.attr('href'));
```

None of it I like, but this looks like autogenerated visual studio code which means it will be ugly and hard to work with  =). I am also assuming that you don't have any control over the source or this would be a lot simpler.

Comment: What doesn't work? This code will work with elements that have already been added to the DOM.

Comment: It pauses on exception: 'ReferenceError'

Comment: Right after `function parse(data)` i added `eval($(data).find('#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserAssetsPane_AssetCategoryRepeater_ctl05_AssetCategorySelector').attr('href'))`  It errors on that line.

Comment: I don't know what that javascript from the href does. It must rely on something on the page after you finish appending elements to it.